# My SQL QUERY for insert into select statement gives error

Tags: php, sql

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `tempahan`(`ic`,`nama`,`tarikh`,`tarikhakhir`,`mula`,`akhir`,`unit`,`bil`,`sebab`) ``SELECT ic, nama
  FROM register";`
```

i use this to select the register column to be inserted in tempahan column.
but it gives me error 'Column count doesn't match value count at row 1'

Comment: You need to `select` exact number of `field` that you wanted to `insert` by `select` statement

Answer (score 3):

just insert into the columns you really want to insert into - as the error states, the number of the columns need to be identical:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `tempahan`(`ic`,`nama`) (SELECT `ic`, `nama`
  FROM `register`)";
```

**update:** you can't use `VALUES()` when using a subquery to get the insert-values. I just corrected this.

Answer (score 2):

Your insert statement for `tempahan` table provides more columns than you select from `register` table. Error message clearly says this. Use this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `tempahan`(`ic`,`nama`) ``SELECT ic, nama FROM register";`
```